# Pandas Add an incremental number based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

Consider a dataframe with a column like this:

```
sequence 
1
2
3
4
5
1
2
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

I wish to create a column when the sequence resets. The sequence is of variable length.

Such that I'd get something like:

```
sequence run
1 1
2 1
3 1
4 1
5 1
1 2
2 2
3 2
1 3
2 3
3 3
4 3
5 3
6 3
7 3
```

Comment: `df['run'] = df['sequence'].eq(1).cumsum()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `diff` then `cumsum`

```
df['run'] = df['sequence'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
Out[349]: 
0     1
1     1
2     1
3     1
4     1
5     2
6     2
7     2
8     3
9     3
10    3
11    3
12    3
13    3
14    3
Name: sequence, dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
dataset['run'] = dataset.groupby('sequence ').cumcount().add(1)
```

output example:

```
sequence run
   y      1
   a      1
   g      1
   a      2
   b      1
   a      3
   b      2
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: The question is how to get use `sequence` to get `run`. Your code does the opposite and uses `run` to get `sequence`.